# In a one-to-many relationship, i want to find data that satisfies all the specific conditions of many

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Product Table

| id(pk) | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | example name1 |
| 2 | example name2 |

Attribute Table

| id(pk) | product_id(fk) | attr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | new |
| 2 | 1 | blue |
| 3 | 1 | car |
| 4 | 2 | new |

In the above table, i want to find a specific product_id with both 'new' and 'blue' attributes(In this situation, expected value is product_id 1)

```
select product_id form attrbute_table where attr in('new', 'blue')
```

did not give me the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose two solutions:

- We can run 2 sub queries, one for each attribute, and then return only the productID's which are in both result sets.
- We can count the number of line returned which contain "blue" or "new".
  NB: If 2 lines are returned we assume that one is "blue" and one is "new". If your data could return 2 lines with the same PID and both "blue" this query would return a false positive. We could around this with a sub-query with DISTINCT but it would not be any simpler than solution 1.

> ```
> create table attribute (
>   ID int primary key,
>   PID int,
>   attr VARCHAR(10));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into attribute values
> (1,1,'new'),
> (2,1,'blue'),
> (3,1,'car'),
> (4,2,'new'),
> (5,3,'blue');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   a.PID
> FROM
> (SELECT PID, attr  FROM attribute WHERE attr ='blue') a
> JOIN
> (SELECT PID,attr  FROM attribute WHERE attr ='new') b
> ON a.PID = b.PID;
> ```
>
> ```
> | PID |
> | --: |
> |   1 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   PID  product_id,
>   COUNT(attr) num_found
> FROM attribute
> WHERE attr = 'blue' or attr = 'new'
> GROUP BY PID
> HAVING COUNT(attr) = 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | num_found
> ---------: | --------:
>          1 |         2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b95dd399712c49090a4b8cde2f940c68)*

Answer (score 0):

'i want to find a specific product_id with both 'new' **and** 'blue' attributes'

so you can use **and** condition

```
select product_id form attrbute_table where attr = 'new' and attr = 'blue'
```

The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

The IN operator is a **shorthand for multiple OR conditions**.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp